# How to extend 2 classes in ExtJS?

Tags: inheritance, extjs, filter, pagination, extjs4.2

Requirement is to add pagination and filters to search contracts.
I have a class called SearchContractInfo which has to extend 'Ext.ux.data.PagingStore' and 'Ext.data.Store' to implement pagination and filers respectively.

Since a class cannot extends 2 classes in ExtJS. What is the alternative solution to extend 2 classes?

Problem is if I extend 'Ext.ux.data.PagingStore', pagination works, filters doesn't.

If i extend 'Ext.data.Store', filter works, pagination doesn't.

I need both pagination and filters to work together.

It would be great help if anyone could come up with a solution.

Code Snippet:

Ext.define('CLAdmin.store.SearchContractInfo', {

```
//extend: 'Ext.ux.data.PagingStore',
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'CLAdmin.model.administration.SearchContractInfo',
 pageSize: 30,
lastOptions: {start: 0, limit: 30, page: 1},
proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    directFn: 'contractAction.searchContracts',
    reader: {
        root: 'records'
    },
    extraParams: {
        searchCriteria: undefined
    },
    listeners: {
        exception: function(me, response, operation, eOpts) {
            var msg = "Application unavailable.Please try after some time";

            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: 'Application',
                msg: msg,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR
            });

        }
    }
},
sorters: [
    {
        property: 'customerNumber',
        direction: 'ASC'
    },
    {
        property: 'startDate',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }
]
```

});

Thanks,
Amith

Answer (score 1):

Use `mixins`:

> In object-oriented programming languages, a mixin is a class that
>   contains methods for use by other classes without having to be the
>   parent class of those other classes. How those other classes gain
>   access to the mixin's methods depends on the language. Mixins are
>   sometimes described as being "included" rather than "inherited".

When you define a class you can pass a [`mixins`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-mixins):

> List of classes to mix into this class.
>
> ```
> Ext.define('CanSing', {
>      sing: function() {
>          alert("For he's a jolly good fellow...")
>      }
> });
>
> Ext.define('Musician', {
>      mixins: ['CanSing']
> });
> ```
>
> In this case the Musician class will get a sing method from CanSing mixin.

Your mixins can extend [`Ext.Mixin`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.Mixin):

> This class is a base class for mixins. These are classes that extend
>   this class and are designed to be used as a mixin by user code.
>
> It provides mixins with the ability to "hook" class methods of the
>   classes in to which they are mixed. For example, consider the destroy
>   method pattern. If a mixin class had cleanup requirements, it would
>   need to be called as part of destroy.